# Falsely identifying duplicate parameter names?

Tags: javascript

I have this `prices` object

```
const prices = {
  hotDog: 453,
  burger: 765,
  sausage: 634,
  corn: 234,
};
```

When I tried to sort them based on prices, the problem occurs in the function arguments of the custom compare function that I wrote

```
const f = Object.entries(prices).sort(([_, p1], [_, p2]) => p1 - p2);
// debugger;
console.table(f);
```

Error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Duplicate parameter name not allowed in this context`

The parameters however have different names -  `p1` and `p2`.

Of course if I remove destructuring and use `Object.entries(prices).sort((p1, p2) => p1[1] - p2[1]);` it works fine, but the question is why does the error say "Duplicate parameters name"?

Comment: Because you have two parameters named `_`...

Comment: Holes in JavaScript are empty elements, not `_` (which is a valid identifier). `[, p1], [, p2]`

Comment: why do you need to sort object properties?

Comment: Ahh okay in Javascript , `_` is an identifier ! That's gonna be a pretty common pitfall for people coming in from other languages :)

Comment: In JS, `_` and `$` are entire libraries. And about the pitfalls, there are bigger ones. Like people coming to JS and thinking they know classes; in JS, same with inheritance and `this` in general. ASI, truthy and falsy values, type coercion, `==` and `===`. And always a treat, asynchronous code and execution order. I've seen people fall over pretty much every concept in JS, because coming from a higher language, they thought they knew how things work and didn't bother to get familiar with the language they were trying to use. And yes, there is a bit of salt in that statement.

Answer (score 1):

your problem comes from `sort(([_, p1], [_, p2])` try with `sort(([x, p1], [y, p2])`

Even if you don't use variable `_`, engine will evaluate those parameters.